# Using Sublime text 2 snippets in PHPStorm?

Tags: sublimetext2, phpstorm

I've been using both Sublime text 2 and PHPStorm for the last few months and am wondering if anyone knows if I can import snippets from Sublime into PHPStorm? Sublime has some really awesome snippets and I'd like to integrate them into PHPStorm without having to add them in manually.

Thank you :)

Comment: Nope. But you can write some script that does that for you -- PhpStorm uses XML for all config files (should be easy to figure out what goes where based on 2-3 custom snippets created in advance), no idea what Sublime uses.

Answer (score 1):

I came across these two solutions:
https://drupal.org/project/phpstorm-templates
https://github.com/DjebbZ/Drupal-PHPStorm-Live-Templates

I hope this will help you in PHPStorm.